# How to create explosion effect using image frames sprite kit swift

Tags: swift

So I created this game where you have to shoot at objects. Now, I have an imageset that replicates an object exploding. I would like to call those images to appear in a sequence so it looks like an explosion after the projectile hits the object. Obviously the images have to be called at the exact location of where the projectile hits the object. Does anyone have any idea on how to make this happen? Here is some code.

```
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()

    playerScore = playerScore + 1
    playerScoreUpdate()

    if (playerScore > 100) {
        let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.3)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(laserCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(monsterCategory)) != 0 {
        projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }
    if playerScore > highScore() {
        saveHighScore(playerScore)
        println("New Highscore = " + highScore().description)
        highScoreLabel.text = "Best score: \(highScore().description)"
    } else {
        println("HighScore = " + highScore().description )  // "HighScore = 100"
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "muteSound" {
            if musicIsPlaying == true {
                backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
                musicIsPlaying = false
            } else if musicIsPlaying == false {
                backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
                musicIsPlaying = true
            }
        } else {
            let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boom")
            projectile.setScale(0.6)
            projectile.position = player.position
            projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
            projectile.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(laserCategory)
            projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(monsterCategory)
            projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
            // 3 - Determine offset of location to projectile
            let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position
            // 4 - Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
            if (offset.y < 0) { return }
            // 5 - OK to add now - you've double checked position
            addChild(projectile)
            // 6 - Get the direction of where to shoot
            let direction = offset.normalized()
            // 7 - Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
            let shootAmount = direction * 1000
            // 8 - Add the shoot amount to the current position
            let realDest = shootAmount + projectile.position
            // 9 - Create the actions
            let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
            let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            if !isStarted {
                start()
            }else{
                projectile.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))

            }
        }
    }
}

func addMonster() {
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "box")
    monster.setScale(0.6)
    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: monster.size)
    monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(monsterCategory)
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(laserCategory)
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    monster.name = "box"

    var random : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(320))
    monster.position = CGPointMake(random, self.frame.size.height + 10)
    self.addChild(monster)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you explosion you could create an `SKSpriteNode` that play the frames you mentioned:

**1.** You're going to need the images as an array of `SKTexture`s. You said you've got you images in an image set so the easiest thing to do may be to create an array using a `for` loop, for example:

```
// I don't know how many images you've got, so I'll use 10.
var textures: [SKTexture] = []
for i in 0..<10 {
    let imageName = "explosion\(i)"
    textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName))
}
```

Alternatively, which is what I would recommend, is to create a Texture Atlas of your images. (For more information on texture atlases see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html)) To create an atlas, make a folder with the extension `.atlas` and adding all your explosion images to it. (Then add this to your project). Here's an extension I wrote to get your sprites out of a texture atlas, ready for animation:

```
extension SKTextureAtlas {
    func textureArray() -> [SKTexture] {
        var textureNames = self.textureNames as! [String]

        // They need to be sorted because there's not guarantee the
        // textures will be in the correct order.
        textureNames.sort { $0 < $1 }
        return textureNames.map { SKTexture(imageNamed: $0) }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas")
let textures = atlas.textureArray()
```

**2.** Now you've got your textures you need to create an `SKSpriteNode` and animate it:

```
let explosion = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[0])

let timePerFrame = // this is specific to your animation.
let animationAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: timePerFrame)
explosion.runAction(animationAction)
```

**3.** Add the sprite to your scene and position it correctly. To add it in the correct place you could use the `contactPoint` variable on `SKPhysicsContact`, after checking it was the projectile hitting an object.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // Other stuff...

    explosion.position = contact.contactPoint
    self.addChild(explosion)
}
```

Hope that helps!